# Pandas drop duplicates with partially completed data in each row and combine data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with duplicate IDs but the data is partially completed in multiple areas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1234, 'Customer A', '123 Street', np.nan, np.nan],
               [1234, 'Customer A', np.nan, '333 Street', np.nan],
               [1234, 'Customer A', '12345 Street', np.nan, np.nan],
               [1234, 'Customer A', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
               [1233, 'Customer B', '444 Street', '3335 Street', np.nan],
               [1233, 'Customer B', '555 Street', '666 Street', np.nan],
               [1233, 'Customer B', '553 Street', '666 Street', 'abc@email.com'],
               [1235, 'Customer C', '1553 Street', '644 Street', 'abc@email.com'],
               [1235, 'Customer C', '2553 Street', '644 Street', 'abc@email.com']],     
               columns=['ID', 'Customer', 'Billing Address', 'Shipping Address', 'Contact'])


df
        ID  Customer    Billing Address Shipping Address    Contact
0   1234    Customer A  123 Street      NaN                 NaN
1   1234    Customer A  NaN             333 Street          NaN
2   1234    Customer A  12345 Street    NaN                 NaN
3   1234    Customer A  NaN             NaN                 NaN
4   1233    Customer B  444 Street      3335 Street         NaN
5   1233    Customer B  555 Street      666 Street          NaN
6   1233    Customer B  553 Street      666 Street          abc@email.com
7   1235    Customer C  1553 Street     644 Street          abc@email.com
8   1235    Customer C  2553 Street     644 Street          abc@email.com
```

I want to preserve all of the data so it creates new columns if the data is there so that it looks like the dataframe below:
[image]

I tried the following but it removes data that I want to preserve.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], inplace=True)
df

    ID      Customer    Billing Address Shipping Address    Contact
0   1234    Customer A  123 Street      NaN                 NaN
4   1233    Customer B  444 Street      3335 Street         NaN
7   1235    Customer C  1553 Street     644 Street          abc@email.com
```

EDIT: I added more data because it was unclear from the original post that there can be IDs with multiple rows.

Comment: Do you have exactly two rows for each ID?

Comment: No, it varies. Some have 3, some may have 5.

Comment: I posted a potential answer, can you try it on a larger portion of your dataset and tell me if it works for you? (BTW, thanks for posting the code that permits to recreate the dataset, it's way faster to answer this way)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using `apply` and create new columns, using `dict` creation for `pd.Series`

```
In [1057]: cols = ['Billing Address', 'Shipping Address']

In [1058]: (df.groupby(['ID', 'Customer'])
              .apply(lambda g: pd.Series({'%s %s' % (x, i+1): v[x] 
                     for i, v in enumerate(g[cols].to_dict('r'))
                     for x in v})))
Out[1058]:
                Billing Address 1 Billing Address 2 Shipping Address 1  \
ID   Customer
1233 Customer B        444 Street        555 Street         333 Street
1234 Customer A        123 Street               NaN                NaN

                Shipping Address 2
ID   Customer
1233 Customer B         666 Street
1234 Customer A         333 Street
```

Comment: Nice solution ~ +1

Comment: I tried this proposal by adding an extra row of data with the same ID (so that there are 3 rows of data with the same ID) and the solution isn't working anymore. Is there a way to make this more generic?

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the original dataframe and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution, though it is not efficient at all in term of memory used in the process.

The idea is to loop over the number of rows you can have for a unique `ID` and merge your dataframe with the nth row:

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ID'])
temp_df = df.drop(new_df.index)
nth_address = 1
while len(temp_df) > 0:
    temp = temp_df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ID'])
    new_df = new_df.merge(temp,suffixes = ('_'+str(nth_address),'_'+str(nth_address+1)),\
                          on = 'ID',how = 'left')
    temp_df = temp_df.drop(temp.index)
    nth_address +=1

    ID      Customer_1  Billing Address_1   Shipping Address_1  Customer_2  Billing Address_2   Shipping Address_2
0   1234    Customer A  123 Street          NaN                 Customer A  NaN                 333 Street
1   1233    Customer B  444 Street          333 Street          Customer B  555 Street          666 Street
```

To fit your desired output, we need to merge on `['ID','Customer']` as it is in your example the same key:

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ID'])
temp_df = df.drop(new_df.index)
nth_address = 1
while len(temp_df) > 0:
    temp = temp_df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ID'])
    new_df = new_df.merge(temp,suffixes = ('_'+str(nth_address),'_'+str(nth_address+1)),on = ['ID','Customer'],how = 'left')
    temp_df = temp_df.drop(temp.index)
    nth_address+=1

    ID      Customer    Billing Address_1   Shipping Address_1  Billing Address_2   Shipping Address_2
0   1234    Customer A  123 Street          NaN                 NaN                 333 Street
1   1233    Customer B  444 Street          333 Street          555 Street          666 Street
```

Comment: I was on a similar path as well but it didn't work for me. I tried your code on a larger dataset with 10,000 rows and it ended up make 20,000 columns.